# Windows 10 stuck on boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, freeze, safe-mode

Today when i started my computer it got stuck on the windows 10 boot logo. The dotted circle stopped spinning after a few times and freezed. I to shut it down using the power button and when i started it automatic repair began. After the repair it showed a blue screen WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR. I tried to boot it up and again the same thing happened (freezed at the boot logo). However I was able to access the safe mode. It worked fine in the safe mode but it still freezes at the boot logo.

Comment: Have you recently changed (hot-plug) any of the hardware while the system was still running? What exactly did you do in safe-mode? Have you tried to run ``msconfig`` and disable all the third party services? Please add more details to your question, otherwise it is hard to guess what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a [hardware problem](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-10/how-to-fix-whea-uncorrectable-error), probably best option is to try a system restore point.

To make a system restore right click on 'This PC' and select properties, then select 'System Protection' and go to the 'System Protection' tab.

[image]

Ref - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-10/how-to-fix-whea-uncorrectable-error

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This avoids issues with link rot as time passes.

Comment: Actually it's not a direct HW error, it's windows messing up with a driver causing something not to work anymore.